# How do I add a Custom Error to Kendo Upload?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am developing an Angular application with the Kendo Upload control and I require the ability to send custom messages to the control's file list. Here is my current code to add ModelState errors to the validationErrors array of the affected file.

```
  errorEventHandler(upload: any, e: ErrorEvent): void {
const file = e.files[0];

file.validationErrors = [];

if (e.response.status !== 400 || !e.response.statusText) {
  file.validationErrors.push('failedToUpload');
  return;
}

let response: any = e.response;

if (response) {
  var modelState = response.error.ModelState;

  for (var key in modelState) {
    if (modelState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      file.validationErrors.push(key);
    }
  }
}
```

}

How can I make the control's error field show my own message instead of the default "File Failed to Upload."?

Comment: Did you work this out? what was the solution?